# Unexpected child "assets.fonts" found under "flutter"

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

I am trying to add a custom font to my flutter app but I get this error `Unexpected child "assets.fonts" found under "flutter".`

My fonts are currently at `lib/assets/fonts` and my `pubspec.yaml` is as follows:

```
name: idk
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets.fonts:
    - family: Beautiful People
      assets.fonts:
        - asset: assets.fonts/BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse-dE0g.ttf
        - asset: assets.fonts/BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse-PYP2.ttf
          style: italic
```

The app runs fine without the `assets.fonts` bit, does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the **assets.fonts** being used as a key in the pubspec.yaml when it should be simply **fonts**, also the path that should be **assets/fonts/...**.

This is the revelant part:

```
  flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

    fonts:
      - family: Beautiful People
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse-dE0g.ttf
          - asset: assets/fonts/BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse-PYP2.ttf
            style: italic
```

Refer to : [Use a custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) and if you have any formatting issues, copy and paste the example in there and replace with your values.

Comment: you are right, `fonts` is the right key, the path is `assets.fonts` tho, not sure why but I am using Android Studio and to be able to create a `directory` I need to create a new package instead, not sure if this is related to the "issue", anyway thank you!

Comment: Hi, that is very odd, you could create a new question for that with the steps you take to create a new folder. I also use android studio, and right clicking over the folder with my app's name and selecting new > directory from the menu does the trick. What happens in your case if you do that?

Comment: I don't have the `directory` option for some reason :/

Comment: Hi, I found a bug related to that [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2539), it may be worth it to try and update your version of android studio in case you're not using the latest one, besides that I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a look later :D